# A-Frame - Setting Height and Width

Tags: css, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to set height and width for my [aframe](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/) element but it fills the window despite any styling I apply.  I'm trying to have my aframe 360 image set to 300px high and 300px wide: [**CODEPEN DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJzaQb)

```
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f66;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a-scene {
  opacity: .5;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, by default, `a-scene` with unmodified source JS will add `class="fullscreen"` to it.

You can either overwrite it, or simply add the `embedded` parameter to your `<a-scene>` tag like so:

```
<a-scene antialias="true" embedded>
    <a-sky src="https://ucarecdn.com/e1c757bc-73ee-4efe-b068-4f778ce212a3/" rotation="0 -20 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

And of course here's a <kbd>[Forked Example](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/PeRyrZ)</kbd>